# Angular - How to use same controller in multiple views in one state without running twice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, angular-material

I'm trying to set up an app that uses a notifications controller to manage functions both on a notifications page/state, and also in the index template for all other pages.

So I've got a specific element in the index template that's present on all and initiates the controller via the ng-controller directive, like this:

```
<md-menu md-position-mode="target-right target" md-offset="10% 0%" ng-controller="notificationsController as notifications">
```

and I also have the notifications state using the same controller initiated via ui-router state definition, like this:

```
.state('notifications', {
    url: '/notifications',
    templateUrl: 'views/notifications.html',
    controller: 'notificationsController',
    controllerAs: 'notifications'
})
```

The problem with this is that the functions in the controller are running twice due to both the state and the ng-controller element both being present when on the notifications page. However, I need the md-menu to access the controller.

How can I set this up or rearrange this so that both the md-menu element and the main notifications state both use the same controller without running functions twice?

Answer (score 0):

From the directive you can access the controller of a parent. Check this 
[Angular example](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate)